# Digital Ocean and dynamic DNS

Tags: dyndns, dynamic-dns, ddns

We are migrating production website from AWS to Digital Ocean, and currently our main concern is static IP that DO provides for droplets.

In case of droplet failure our static IP address would be lost, our DNS settings would become invalid, causing up to 48h of potential downtime.

We are thinking about using a dynamic DNS service for our website, like dyn.com.

What downsides of using such setup would be? DYN.COM <-> DO

Comment: Why would your IP be lost?

Comment: Because, when droplet is destroyed (intentionally or as a result of a failure) they don't guarantee that next IP will be the same one. Eg., when you execute "migrate-resize", they say IP will "almost always" be preserved, but that is not 100% sure.

Comment: Well in that case, find a new provider. That is a *very* unprofessional way for DO to carry out business.

Comment: They might be unprofessional in this sense, but what about the setup I asked? Can I make it work with Dyn.com ?

Comment: Any setup you choose is going to be subject to the vagaries of DNS cache expiry.

Answer (score 2):

The downside would be that dynamic DNS is still DNS, and therefore subject to DNS caching (and violations of the specified TTL are rampant on the internet - AOL was infamous for forcing all TTLs to a minimum of one hour regardless of what's specified by the authoritative name server).

Quite simply DigitalOcean does not seem to be an appropriate solution for you based on the information provided. You should consider using a different provider (or sticking with Amazon).